# EMERGENCY: Everything on our Magento 1.9.4 is all of a sudden discounted by 19% exactly!

Tags: discount, product-prices

```
Magento 1.9.4
Smartwave Porto
```

We never ever never had this problem. All of a sudden - **ALL of our products on our Magento 1.9.4 website are discounted by exactly 19%**. *This is a huge problem for us!* I looked around the Admin panel and products themselves but I cannot find where this is coming from! There is also a tab called 'Daily Deal' but in the settings it says: Enable Daily Deal = NO.

**How can I find out what is causing this and how can I switch it back?**

There was 1172 records found in the `Daily Deal -> Manage Deals` - I deleted them all, flushed Cache and reindexed but it didn't help.

I also deleted EVERYTHING from `Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules`

There were 1607 records found in:

Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules

they have an ID (such as 2048), Rule Name: usually something like Alert #6072. Coupon Code (such as 603015BCE252D) and Expiry date and Website. I think this has to do with the Abandoned Cart extension we have from Amasty. These cannot be deleted en masse but most of them have just 5% discount defined in the Actions.

I have disabled the (Daily Deal) Magegiant_Dailydeal extension in:

`System -> Configuration -> Advanced --> Advanced` but it did not help.

Can I disable something else here to stop the 19% discount?

It looks like this on the front end:

[image]

Comment: Hey Can you check Shopping cart OR Catalog Rule enable ? In Admin Promotion tabs.
you check below this link screenshot for reference https://bsscommerce.com/blog/shopping-cart-price-rules-in-magento-1-version/

Comment: @Jitendra Patel there is nothing in the Catalog Price Rules and we have 1607 records in Shopping Cart Price rules but these have to do with the Abandoned Cart extension by Amasty which I believe sends out an Email to customer with a coupon code to 'come back and finish the order' but there all seem to be for 5%! I am really desperate now - this never happened before!

Comment: @Jitendra Patel Is there any way to turn these modules off completely somewhere in Advanced/Developer? I have to solve this very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in our case actually was that **I tried to set up 2 coupons (for 10% off each)** previously in

```
Promotions --> Catalog Price Rules
```

and **I have done that incorrectly** where the *the discount was calculated and applied on top of each other hence the 19% exactly.*

Even-though I deleted all the items in the Catalog Price Rules and deleted Cache and re-indexed via both the Admin panel and SSH, Magento did not for some reason recognize that the Price Rules have in fact been deleted. Magento did see this change after **I clicked on the 'Apply Rules' button** in:

```
Promotions --> Catalog Price Rules
```

[image]